# creating multiple div elements in <b-card>

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I would like to add 3 div elements in a top section of a card where currently there is an image. I would like to add an image, logo and text message in place of that image. What can I do???

Thanks in Advance,

Here's my code

1)HTML

```
<div class="card">

  <b-card no-body
          style="width: 20rem;"
          img-src="https://placekitten.com/380/200"
          >

      <b-list-group  class="group">
          <b-list-group-item>Anvay Joshi</b-list-group-item>
          <b-list-group-item>Computer</b-list-group-item>
          <b-list-group-item>A-1103</b-list-group-item>
          <b-list-group-item>30-11-1997</b-list-group-item>
          <b-list-group-item>anvay.joshi@viit.ac.in</b-list-group-item>
          <b-list-group-item>9766583977</b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
      <b-button href="#" variant="primary">QR Code</b-button>
  </b-card>
```

2)CSS

```
.group {
        text-align: center;
       }

.header{
        text-align: center;
       }

.card  {
         margin: 25px 120px 25px 240px;
         border: none;
       }
```

My Actual output looks like as shown

> [/Users/anvayjoshi/Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4433.png)

My expected output is the top part of the card as shown

> [/Users/anvayjoshi/Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybqgq.jpg)

Please help me !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `img-src` attribute on `b-card`, you can just add a new `b-list-group-item`.

[Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nardnob/cyd21jks/) demonstrating that, and [an image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nwdo.png).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  }
});
```

```css
.image {
  float: left;
}
  
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
  
.text {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

.group {
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  margin: 10px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="card">
    <b-card no-body style="width: 20rem;">
      <b-list-group class="group">
        <b-list-group-item>
          <img class="image" src="https://placekitten.com/100/100" />
          <img class="logo" src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" />
          <div class="text">
            Vishwakarma Institute of Information Technology
          </div>
        </b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>Anvay Joshi</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>Computer</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>A-1103</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>30-11-1997</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>anvay.joshi@viit.ac.in</b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item>9766583977</b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
      <b-button href="#" variant="primary">QR Code</b-button>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</div>
```